# Unique keys in N:M Relation SQL Server & C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, constraints

I have a table called `cars` and one called `roads`

```
Roads:                        Cars:

Name      Road_Id             Owner     Car_Id
-------------------           ---------------------
roade45       1               Hugo        1
roade20       2               Eson        2
roade10       3               Karl        3
```

I need to create an N:M relation between these (one can can drive on many roads, one road can have many cars).

It is a dumb example, but it **needs** to be an N:M relation.

I do this relation by creating an other table called `cars_roads` with these columns

```
Road_id | Car_id | uniqueValue
```

My problem is now that I have no idea on how to get the `uniqueValue` to take form, this value will be used to prevent doubles from occurring, eg. the same car is added to the same road a second time.

My table is created using this code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_cars_roads] 
(
    [Road_id]   INT NOT NULL,
    [car_id] INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Tbl_Road_id] FOREIGN KEY ([Road_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tbl_Cars] ([Road_id]),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Tbl_car_id] FOREIGN KEY ([car_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tbl_Roads] ([car_id])
)
```

How can I add an `uniqueValue` key and make it work as explained to this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should make unique group you want.

```
CONSTRAINT [UQ_CarRoads] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Road_id] ASC,
    [car_id] ASC
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following code after your last constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT [UK_Road_Car] UNIQUE ([Road_id], [car_id])
```